# How to call Oracle stored procedure

Tags: parameter-passing, oracle-apex, buttonclick

I am working on Oracle Apex forms. I have to call an Oracle stored procedure on click of a button and pass input parameters.

I am able to call the Procedure but do not know how to pass input parameters in it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking **specific** programming questions. Please see [Before You Ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before).

Answer (score 0):

If parameter value stored on APEX form you should call like this `proc_name(:Pxxx_ITEM_NAME, :Pxxx_ITEM_NAME2)`